# Spark runtime error: spark.metrics.sink.MetricsServlet cannot be instantialized

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-spark, maven-3

I got invocation target exception when running project with spark 1.3 lib in maven in IntelliJ.

I got met this error only in IntelliJ IDE. After I deployed the jar and ran via spark-submit, the error went out.

Any one has met with the same problem before? I hope to fix this problem so as to do easy-debugging. otherwise I have to package the jar every time when I want to run the code.

details are as below:

```
    2015-04-21 09:39:13 ERROR MetricsSystem:75 - Sink class org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.MetricsServlet cannot be instantialized
    2015-04-21 09:39:13 ERROR TrainingSFERunner:144 - java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    2015-04-20 16:08:44 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:59 - Registered BlockManager
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSinks$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSinks$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:181)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.registerSinks(MetricsSystem.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.start(MetricsSystem.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:390)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
        at spark.mllibClassifier.JavaRandomForests.run(JavaRandomForests.java:105)
        at spark.mllibClassifier.SparkMLlibMain.runMain(SparkMLlibMain.java:263)
        at spark.mllibClassifier.JavaRandomForests.main(JavaRandomForests.java:221)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleSerializers.<init>(Ljava/util/List;)V
        at com.codahale.metrics.json.MetricsModule.setupModule(MetricsModule.java:223)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:469)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.MetricsServlet.<init>(MetricsServlet.scala:45)
```

My pom file is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>projects</groupId>
    <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
            </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>colt</groupId>
            <artifactId>colt</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I suggest that you try to read about how you should ask questions on stackoverflow because this is really a low quality question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it looks like it could be that your IDE environment is giving you a different version of Jackson than the Spark runtime env.

Comment: @MartinSerrano Thanks for your reply. Do you know how to check with Jackson version for both environments? And how to change the setting if different?

Comment: perhaps add your pom.xml to the question.  i don't really know, it was just a guess

Comment: @MartinSerrano Thanks. Just added pom file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strangely, I found the error didn't come out any more when I move the spark related dependencies to the front.

```
   <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        //....the rest dependencies....

    </dependencies>
```

So the sequence of the dependencies matters! Any one knows why?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is in jackson dependency. I had similar issue and problem was multiple jackson-core and jackson-databind versions. I think it is scala related issue. Anyway add this 2 jackson dependencies to pom with lower versions and it should work. Maybe you will not find right version from first try. This one works for me.

```
    <jackson-core.version>2.4.4</jackson-core.version>
    <spark.version>2.3.0</spark.version>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>        
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jackson dependency issue - I had spark3.0.3-hadoop2.7 version, and had 2 versions of jackson annotation and databind jars. Removed those, and this error got solved.