# SparkConf not started of Spark job

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, distributed-computing, kafka-consumer-api

Here below is my code.

Exception throwing in the first line of code, Below error raising while debugging the code.

Is there I am missing something?

```
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaKafkaWordCount").setMaster("local[*]");
        ;
        // Create the context with 2 seconds batch size
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(1000));

        Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<>();
        topicMap.put("ParsedDataQueue", 1);

        JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, "9.32.165.247:2181", "5",
                topicMap);
```

I am getting below error raising while on a first line itself!!.

```
16/11/15 06:10:04 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
16/11/15 06:10:05 ERROR MetricsSystem: Sink class org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.MetricsServlet cannot be instantiated
16/11/15 06:10:05 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSinks$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSinks$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.registerSinks(MetricsSystem.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.start(MetricsSystem.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:540)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:874)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.<init>(JavaStreamingContext.scala:140)
    at spark.ScoreConsumer.main(ScoreConsumer.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleSerializers.<init>(Ljava/util/List;)V (loaded from file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.0.0/jackson-databind-2.0.0.jar by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@86b3226c) called from class com.codahale.metrics.json.MetricsModule (loaded from file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-json/3.1.2/metrics-json-3.1.2.jar by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@86b3226c).
    at com.codahale.metrics.json.MetricsModule.setupModule(MetricsModule.java:223)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:469)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.MetricsServlet.<init>(MetricsServlet.scala:49)
    ... 18 more
16/11/15 06:10:05 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://9.98.171.228:4040
16/11/15 06:10:05 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/11/15 06:10:05 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/11/15 06:10:05 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/11/15 06:10:05 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/11/15 06:10:05 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/11/15 06:10:05 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSinks$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSinks$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.registerSinks(MetricsSystem.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.start(MetricsSystem.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:540)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:874)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.<init>(JavaStreamingContext.scala:140)
    at spark.ScoreConsumer.main(ScoreConsumer.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module/SimpleSerializers.<init>(Ljava/util/List;)V (loaded from file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.0.0/jackson-databind-2.0.0.jar by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@86b3226c) called from class com.codahale.metrics.json.MetricsModule (loaded from file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-json/3.1.2/metrics-json-3.1.2.jar by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@86b3226c).
    at com.codahale.metrics.json.MetricsModule.setupModule(MetricsModule.java:223)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:469)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.MetricsServlet.<init>(MetricsServlet.scala:49)
    ... 18 more
```

In the project following is a depedencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.0-alpha3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/29742480/5088142

Comment: It is a dependency issue of jackson core,please check by changing version and mvn clean install after mvn prjct update.

Comment: It may also possible that your dependencies sequence is wrong put spark depn. at first priority,

Comment: @BhaumikThakkar Thank you for info. Can you please tell me what was going wrong..

Comment: how you are deploying your app? by spark submit?

Comment: if yes try by adding your jacson jar at runtime.(in spark submit cmd)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with Jackson as it is a common library used in different open source projects. You need to make sure that you have the same version for both `jackson-databind` and `jackson-core`.

You can use [Maven dependency tree tool](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) to find exactly what depends on what and fix the problem properly:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=com.fasterxml.jackson.core
```

There is a chance that you can just fix it by adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But some times you need to dig deeper :|